# Can $\int xe^{6x} dx$ be solved without integration-by-parts

Tags: integration

This integral

$$\int xe^{6x} dx$$

is easily solved with integration by parts, but is it possible to solve with U substitution or some other method.

Comment: It can certainly be changed into a different indefinite integral by the use of $u$-substitution, e.g. $u=e^{6x}$.  I don't think this makes the problem easier though.

Answer (score 2):

Let $xe^{6x} = t \implies e^{6x}(6x+1)dx =dt$

- So first multiply and divide the given integrand by $6$.
- Then add and subtract $1$

$$\int xe^{6x}dx = \frac16\int6xe^{6x}dx = \frac16\int(6x+1)e^{6x}dx -\frac16\int e^{6x}dx = \frac16t-\frac1{36}e^{6x}+c\\ = \frac16xe^{6x}-\frac1{36}e^{6x}+c\\=\frac{1}{36}(6x-1)e^{6x}+c$$

Comment: This is basicly per partes.

Comment: @Aqua Yeah but it doesn't involve the formula $\int udv = uv -\int vdu$ directly.

Comment: @Aqua: I disagree, there is a true $t$-substitution, though you need a trick to solve it.

Comment: This can be restated as use of the Ansatz $\int xe^{6x}dx=(Ax+B)e^{6x}+C$, whence we differentiate to solve for $A,\,B$. If that's parts, any proof is parts.

Answer (score 1):

Some general methods using power series can be used for such problems. Let $\, f(x) := \exp(6x)\,$ and
 $\, g(x) := \int x f(x)\,dx.\,$
Assuming an algebraic relation between $\,x,\, f(x),\,$ and
$\,g(x),\,$ use an **algebraic relation finding** tool with series expansions up to $O(x^{12})$ to
get $$ 0 = 1 - f(x) - 36\,g(x) + 6\,xf(x). $$
Solving this linear equation for $\,g(x)\,$ gives the solution
$$ g(x) = (1-f(x))/36 + x f(x)/6$$
plus a constant, of course. This method works because
the integral $\,g(x)\,$ has an algebraic relation with
both $\,x\,$ and $\,f(x).\,$

Answer (score 1):

Through power series:

Let's remember that:

$ e^x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}  $

Then,

$\int xe^{6x} dx =  \int x \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(6x)^n}{n!} dx$

$\int xe^{6x} dx =  \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty   \int \frac{6^n x^{n+1}}{n!} dx$ =

$ = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty    \frac{6^n \int x^{n+1}}{n!} dx = $

$  \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty    \frac{6^n x^{n+2}}{n!(n+2)} dx  = $

Therefore,

$ \int xe^{6x} dx = x^2 \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty    \frac{(6x)^n}{n!(n+2)} dx   $

Answer (score 1):

This method is how to kill a fly with a gun, anyway it's working. You need to find a primitive of $xe^{6x}$. Search it as $p(x)e^{6x}$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of first degree. This is justified by observing that if you have a function like
$$f(x)=p(x)e^{kx}$$ it is $$f'(x)=(p'(x)+kp(x))e^{kx}$$ and $q(x)=p'(x)+kp(x)$ has the same degree as $p(x)$. In our case it must be

$$(p(x)e^{6x})'=p'(x)e^{6x}+6p(x)e^{6x}=xe^{6x}$$ for each $x \in \mathbb R$. This means that
$$p'(x)+6p(x)=x$$ for each $x \in \mathbb R$. Now, put $p(x)=ax+b$ and you get
$$a+6ax+6b=x$$. Therefore $a=\frac{1}{6}$ and $b=-\frac{1}{36}$ so that an primitive is $$F(x)=(\frac{1}{6}x-\frac{1}{36})e^{6x}.$$ I tell once again: I did it just for sake of find an alternative way, and not because this is a good method. Integration by parts is very much better.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$I(\alpha) = \int_{-\infty}^x e^{\alpha t}dt = \frac1\alpha e^{\alpha x}$$

and recognize,

$$\int xe^{\alpha x} dx = I'(\alpha) + C = \left(\frac x\alpha  - \frac1{\alpha^2}\right)e^{\alpha x}+ C$$

Thus,

$$\int xe^{6 x} dx= \left(\frac x6 - \frac1{36}\right)e^{6x} + C$$